# how to troubleshoot django 'internal server error'

Tags: python, django

a similar question was asked 7 years ago, but the answer/comments were not that helpful and maybe not current.

I'm developing a new website and relatively new to django.

At times django provides a very detailed error response (very helpful) but other times it simply says 'internal server error' (less helpful).

why is this and what is a good method for troubleshooting 'internal server error' errors?

Comment: If it shows just `Internal Server Error`, that means your `debug` is set to `False` in `settings.py`. Try setting the value of `debug` to `True`(`debug=True`) and it will give detailed error response for debugging the error

Comment: @Ayush, just checked in settings.py it is set as....`DEBUG = True`

Comment: So, can you pls add the image of the error page in the question for more clarity

Comment: It may be due to syntax error in your python code. Try viewing the logs from terminal (if you're using `runserver` or Apache error log if you're using WSGI). Also, it'd be good if you can add the question you found.

Comment: @dibery - thats really the root of my question. There are times I get a helpful and detailed error message from django and other times I get a vague (almost useless) error message.  What assumptions can I make when I see the `Internal Server Error` ?  For example does that mean the error is in my `setings.py` or `urls.py` code and NOT `views.py` or my templates?

Comment: @user3808752 When an exception occurs before a request, you'll see the internal server error. For example, a syntax error comes before a request so you'll see it (also true for missing imports), while an exception raised when Django is processing a request will be reported to you.

Answer (score 1):

this is what works for me.

if django returns a debug screen I use that.

if I just get the 'internal server error' message I run `python3 /home/django/django_project/manage.py check`